# Can we congratulate someone on a birthday or a new year?

Tags: spoken-english, conversation

What verb should I use instead of an ellipsis?

Suppose I said "Happy birthday" to John. Then, I decided to tell my friend that I ... John with/on his birthday.

The point is I want to highlight that I didn't just **said** "Happy birthday" to John, but I sort of congratulated him on it. But I don't think the verb "congratulate" fits here, because it's more about success and achievements rather than an age mark.

P.S. The same question can be applied to the following situation:

- I ... Carmen with/on a New Year.

Comment: You *can* use "congratulate" in that occasion - but it will sound funny, silly, or sarcastic. But nothing unreasonable between friends. *"Happy birthday man. Congrats! You have lived for 25 years. Never thought you would make it this far."* or *"Congratulations for having lived this long man! It must have been hard considering the things you do."* Ah well ...

Comment: Yeah, I just wondered if there is such a verb which I could use in a neutral situation, not in an informal one :)

Comment: "wished" - I wished John many happy returns of the day.

Comment: Oh, okay. And could I also say "I wished John a Happy New Year"?

Comment: Yes, of course you can.

Comment: Alright, thank you!

Comment: [wish](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wish): to hope or express hope for another person's success or happiness or pleasure on a particular occasion